# Debian 5 server is randomly shutting down

Tags: debian, vps

My debian 5 vps is suffering from random shutdowns. I reinstalled it several times, the hosts moved me to a different physical box, check the install image and said everyone else also uses it and is fine.

Heres the output from syslog

```
Mar 27 00:19:19 noobintraining-1 -- MARK --
Mar 27 00:32:01 noobintraining-1 shutdown[18142]: shutting down for system halt
Mar 27 00:32:06 noobintraining-1 init: Switching to runlevel: 0
Mar 27 00:32:06 noobintraining-1 xinetd[15907]: Exiting...
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: received control channel command 'stop -p'
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: shutting down: flushing changes
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: stopping command channel on 127.0.0.1#953
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: stopping command channel on ::1#953
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: no longer listening on ::#53
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: no longer listening on 127.0.0.1#53
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: no longer listening on 89.238.172.132#53
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 named[15865]: exiting
Mar 27 00:32:07 noobintraining-1 exiting on signal 15
```

Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Since it's a VPS, it's usually possible to shut down the container via some management interface. Or there may be other means to send a shutdown signal for the container. Can you eliminate that possibility?

Comment: I did try and look at everything in the management panel but nothing stopped it / looks like it was shutting it down.

Comment: Although, when I start a shutdown from the panel it shows the same stuff in syslog

Comment: So, you're already on a different physical machine, with a fresh install, that works for others? That doesn't leave many options available. Is there a slight chance, that someone else has access to the panel, or can send the shutdown signal by some means? Did you try changing passwords? Or is there some special additional software installed on your system?

Comment: I am the only one that has access to the server but I will try changing it later and see if that changes things. I think it may be something to do with the panel though, i shalkl ask the provider.

Answer (score 1):

Someone could be pressing the power button performing ACPI shutdown or it just might be an issue with [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface). The system could also have sensor problems and thus thinks it is becoming to hot and shutsdown.

Try setting acpi to off in the kernel boot options. This is most likely performed in grub(/boot/grub/menu.lst).

You should look for the section that looks like:

```
title           Debian GNU/Linux, kernel 2.6.26-2-amd64
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.26-2-amd64
```

Add acpi off to the kernel line like this:

```
   kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.26-2-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro acpi=off
```

Reboot and try out your new setting!

EDIT: if it is an ACPI issue you may find more info in the log file:

```
 /var/log/acpid
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response. I can't see any menu.lst file on the server or a log for acpid. The server is a VPS if that makes a difference.